# FreePBX on Wifi can't connect to the server

Tags: wifi, freepbx

I configured wifi on `FreePBX`. When I run `FreePBX` I see wlan0 and `ipv6` address. I can ping that address from other machine from the same LAN network.

`iwconfig`:

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11 ESSID:"my name ssid"
      Mode:Managed Frequency:2.412 GHz Access Point: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      Bit Rate=86.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22dBm
      Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=40/70 Signal level=-70dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc: 19 Missed beacon:0
```

I called commands:

```
dhclient -r
dhclient wlan0
```

And when I type `ifconfig` I have `IPv4` address assigned to `wlan0`. But I can't ping that address from other machine in the same LAN network.
I can't connect using webbrowser too.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I can't ping IPv4 address from other machine, IPv6 I can. The question is why?

Comment: Edit the question and add it in the question, not as comment. But that's not enough. You have to provide the configuration of other systems and of your system (`ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` (and if there's really IPv6 somewhere: `ip -6 route`)). Forget about IPv6: it's probably link local IPv6 which isn't routable. I say probably, because again you didn't put the information in the question. Also provide firewall settings.

Comment: @A.B thanks it help me, if you want, you can write answer and I will approve it

Comment: Hum, I can't see what I could possibliy have solved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@A.B. it help me:

```
ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route (and if there's really IPv6 somewhere: ip -6 route)
```

Thanks